# active apps do not appear in the dock

Tags: plank

Don't know what happened and why it doesn't work any more (EOS 6 Odin).
If (for example) I open LibreOffice Calc it just doesn't show in the dock.
It always used to?
Has anything changed? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have since discovered that using Multitasking View seem to be the only way of dealing with it in ODIN? I guess I got some learning to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using "Multitasking View" solves my issue.

Will have to get used to it :-)